# ¿Algún ORM sencillo para PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, eloquent, orm

Tengo que resolver un ejercicio en PHP, y me parece que el camino "correcto" (de buenas prácticas) sería utilizar un ORM.

Entiendo que se pueden utilizar los ORM más comunes, como, por ejemplo, Eloquent de Laravel sin la necesidad de utilizar Laravel. No obstante, me han pedido enviar un fichero .sql con la creación de las tablas y los inserts de los datos. Hasta dónde llega mi conocimiento, si utilizo Eloquent no puedo crear las bases de datos directamente con SQL, sino que tendría que crear "migraciones" y que éste se encargue sólo.

La pregunta es ¿Hay buenas prácticas para establecer la conexión con una base de datos MysQL sin la necesidad de utilizar un ORM? o ¿existe un ORM que me permita utilizar SQL?

Si utilizo MySQLi con OOP ¿podemos considerarla buena práctica? [Ver primera respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321795/oop-mysqli-connect)

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola! Eloquent te permite utilizar SQL crudo, pero de todas formas, oriéntandome más a tu necesidad, te aconsejaría mires [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/index.php). Es más ligero y el tema de las migraciones lo maneja de una forma más "opcional".

De hecho, su primer ejemplo es importar un fichero e instalar el ORM en menos de un minuto.

Comment: Lo voy a mirar. Muchas gracias, Marcelo